# Python Not Removing Char From String

Tags: python

Iv tried multiple times and ways for removing the extra punctuation from the string.

```
import string

class NLP:

    def __init__(self,sentence):

        self.sentence  = sentence.lower()

        self.tokenList = []


    #problem were the punct is still included in word
    def tokenize(self, sentence):

        for word in sentence.split():
            self.tokenList.append(word)

            for i in string.punctuation:
                if(i in word):
                    word.strip(i)
                    self.tokenList.append(i)
```

quick explanation of the code...
What it is suppose to do is to split each word and punctuation and store them in a list. But when i have punctuation next to a word it stays with the word. Below is an example where a comma remains grouped with the word 'hello'

```
['hello,' , ',' , 'my' , 'name' , 'is' , 'freddy']
      #^
     #there's the problem
```

Comment: Are the types of punctuation marks known beforehand? Do you know, for example, that there are only fullstops and commas?

Comment: if you mean by in the sentence, then no. The input can be anything from user input. If you meant by the program identifying the char, then yes, that is in string.punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a different approach:

```
import string
import itertools

def tokenize(s):
    tokens = []
    for k,v in itertools.groupby(s, lambda c: c in string.punctuation):
        tokens.extend("".join(v).split())
    return tokens
```

A test:

```
>>> tokenize("this is, a test, you know")
['this', 'is', ',', 'a', 'test', ',', 'you', 'know']
```

Comment: @Freddy-FazBear I'm glad it works for you. Note that in your code, you're not assigning to result of `word.strip(i)` to anything. That's why the character is never removed from the string.

Comment: oh, never realized that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

A Python string is immutable.  Therefore, `word.strip(i)` does **not** "change `word` in place" as you seem to assume; rather, it returns a **copy** of `word`, modified by the `.strip(i)` operation -- which removes only from the **ends** of the string, so that's not what you want either (unless you know the punctuation occurs in the word in a peculiar order).

```
def tokenize(self, sentence):
    for word in sentence.split():
        punc = []
        for i in string.punctuation:
            howmany = word.count(i)
            if not howmany: continue
            word = word.replace(i, '')
            punc.extend(howmany*[i])
        self.tokenList.append(word)
        self.tokenList.extend(punc)
```

This assumes it's OK to have all the punctuation, one per item, **after** the cleaned-up word, independently of where within the word the punctuation appeared.

For example, should the `sentence` be `(here)`, the list would be `['here', '(', ')']`.

If there are stricter constraints on the ordering of things in the list, please edit your Q to express them clearly -- ideally with examples of desired input and output, too!